# First login attempt aways fail, second works on SQL Server Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I have a SQL Database hosted in azure.

When I try to login, the first attempt always fails, the second works as expected.

The error I receive is

> Cannot connect to databasex.database.windows.net.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

Why is this happening and how to solve this?

Comment: This happens to me as well..ONLY when i left the database in unused state for more than a week or so .

Comment: Note that Azure requires a TCP connection - named pipes will not connect to Azure. You can try adding `tcp:` to the front of the server name in the connection string, i.e. `Server=tcp: mysqlserver.ctp.database.windows.net;Database=master;User ID=me@mysqlserver ;Password=pwd!pwd;Trusted_Connection=False;`

Comment: This has been the case for me as well for as long as I can remember. While I don't recall seeing anything official on the matter, I do believe this is probably due to unused databases being put in an offline state after an extended period of inactivity.

Comment: Forcing TCP connection solved the problem. Thanks @Laughing Vergil.

Comment: Glad to help, @AndySchmitt